# Backup plungin in jenkins is not able to restore the backupzip in linux

Tags: linux, jenkins, backup

I have created 2 fresh gcp virtual machine with same ubuntu 18.04. Only difference is Machine1 is jenkins with suggested plugins at the start and Machine2 is not with any plugin.

I created one job in Machine1 just to clone a git repo.

and I backup the configuration and demo job in zip file.
I copy this zip file in Machine 2 and tried to restore.

but the restore process never goes ahead than this[image]

Comment: Iis this related [JENKINS-64818](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/JENKINS-64818)

Comment: @IanW this is not related . there is no error displayed or no artifacts involved.

Comment: Do you see anything in the system logs? Are you using the 10yr old [Backup](https://plugins.jenkins.io/backup/#releases) plugin?

Comment: Tjere are [35 open issues](https://issues.jenkins.io/issues/?jql=project%20%3D%20JENKINS%20AND%20component%20%3D%20backup-plugin) for the plugin. Any applicable?

Comment: @IanW yes it is 10 Years old [backup](https://plugins.jenkins.io/backup/) plugin